# Is there any JDBC client SSL/TLS support for MonetDB?

Tags: monetdb

Does anyone know if MonetDB supports encrypted JDBC connections using SSL/TLS? If so, is there a driver that supports it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it doesn't.  Also, we're not aware of any external drives that support this.

In fact, MonetDB does not support any form of secure connections. If you need that, you need to use an ssh tunnel.